# ACPI Error: Field [TBF3] - Can't boot properly

Tags: boot, 16.04, acpi

Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly shu down because the battery ended, and now I can't boot properly. I can reach a root terminal or I can boot to recovery mode. This is what I get after boot:

```
ACPI Error: Field [TBF3] at bit offset/length 32786/491520 exceeds size of target Buffer (262144 bits) (20170531/dsopcode-235)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO.POP2.VGA.GETB, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \SB.PCIO.POP2.VGA._ROM, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
/dev/sda1: clean, 741668/8011776 files, 7170116/32043264 blocks
Welcome to emergency mode! 
[...]
```

I tried to check the logs and at the end I see:

```
[...]
kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCIO.POP2.VGA._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCIO.POP2.VGA._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170531/nsarguments-95)
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending fence...
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending object tree...
```

I have no idea what I'm looking at. I've tried with `fsck /` from recovery mode and it gives me no error. I tried to set `acpi=off` or `acpi=strict` from grub, but nothing solved the issue. I need help to recover my system.

Comment: I was trying to boot in recovery mode (it worked for a few times while I was trying to solve this) and for a moment I saw something like filesystem inconsistency in home folder or something like that. I'm trying to check that log better but I'm not sure how, I'll keep the post updated

Comment: reading various posts around I guess the ACPI error might not be the real issue but something that might be pre-existent but unnoticed, I tried to select an older kernel on GRUB and didn't show that ACPI error while still going in emergency mode only ( i could only choose to go in root shell, no graphic allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fell again on the same error again after 1 year and I forgot the solution so I'm posting it here this time.

ACPI Error it's not start-up blocking. reading journalctl -xb better the error is with filesystem error code 4 which is fixed with:

```
fsck /dev/sda<n>
```